# How to remove the last bracket with Regex

Tags: regex

I am wondering how to remove the last square bracket and its content for the String with Regular Expression:

AMES-13TH-19-G-309-Johnson County [Private Room] [CCTV]

the group 1 should return:

AMES-13TH-19-G-309-Johnson County [Private Room]

,so [CCTV] should be deleted. 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```js
var str = 'AMES-13TH-19-G-309-Johnson County [Private Room][CCTV]' ;

var patt = /\[\w*\](?![^\[]*\[)/g ;

var result = str.replace(patt,'') ;

console.log( result ) ;
```

Comment: Your code happens to work since the last part consists of "word" character, and the "Private Room" has a space in between.

Comment: Try with `[First] [Second]`. Your code will replace both.

Comment: This doesn't work when there are more than two bracketed groups or less than two bracketed groups.

Answer (score 2):

This code removes the last `[bracketed group]` found in the string.

```js
var str = 'AMES-13TH-19-G-309-Johnson County [Private Room] [CCTV]' ;
var result = str.replace(/^(.*)\[[^\]]*\]/, '$1');
console.log(result);
```

The regex basically starts looking from the end of the string, due to the greediness of `(.*)`, and it looks for the pattern `\[[^\]]*\]` (open bracket - any number of non-close-bracket - close bracket). If we found a match, we will toss away the bracketed part and retain the part in front.